# Org export: timestamps not working as expected

Tags: org-mode, org-export

I'm attempting to modify the formatting of timestamps when they are exported to either HTML or TeX/pdf. I have tried two different ways, neither one of which works. The first way was [here](http://endlessparentheses.com/better-time-stamps-in-org-export.html) and I put that code in my dotemacs file. However, I get a symbol's value is void error for `org-export-filter-timestamp-functions` when I open emacs.

The second way I tried, which also does not work is to attempt the example in [the manual](http://orgmode.org/manual/Advanced-configuration.html#Advanced-configuration) under "defining filters for individual files." I copy/pasted the text into the beginning of my org document, but this does not change the formatting of timestamps at all.

```
#+BIND: org-export-filter-timestamp-functions (tmp-f-timestamp)
 #+BIND: org-export-filter-strike-through-functions (tmp-f-strike-through)
 #+begin_src emacs-lisp :exports results :results none
   (defun tmp-f-timestamp (s backend info)
     (replace-regexp-in-string "&[lg]t;\\|[][]" "" s))
   (defun tmp-f-strike-through (s backend info) "")
 #+end_src
```

Comment: I assume `org-export-filter-timestamp-functions` is a quite new variable of `org-mode`. Presumably, it is introduced in `org-mode` 8.3. What is your `org-version`? For modifying time-stamps see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23297422. /org-mode-timestamp-format-when-exported. Note that the solution using `org-export-filter-timestamp-functions` is from the year 2015. My `org-version` is 8.2.5h and I don't have `org-export-filter-timestamp-functions` either.

Comment: Note also that `org-export.el` was in `contrib` and not in the main org-mode branch according to this link: https://github.com/tkf/org-mode/blob/master/contrib/lisp/org-export.el , That git entry seems to be from year 2012.

Comment: It would be nice if someone out there could check for the variable `org-export-filter-timestamp-functions` in `org-mode` 8.3.

Comment: @Tobias - Thanks. I just updated to org 8.3.2 and still have this problem. I downloaded org-plus-contrib, but this doesn't seem to contain org-export.el file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `org-export-filter-timestamp-functions` is defined in `ox.el`.
You need to add

`(require 'ox)`

in front of the code where you want to use `org-export-filter-timestamp-functions`.

Note: My comments above were wrong. (Sorry about that.)